# Down log on ME 3400

Tags: cisco-catalyst

What command is used to check down log on ME 3400. I am trying to see if there was any bounce on the interfaces.

Please help me out.

Comment: `show log | inc LINK-3-UPDOWN` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Fizzle should make that an answer. Softball question, but no reason to not offer it as the most-obvious, simple answer.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

The quickest/easiest way is to use the `show logging` [command](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/fundamentals/command/reference/cf_book/cf_s2.html#wp1565683).  It would produce an output similar to below.

```
Router#
00:00:46: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Port-channel1, changed state to up
00:00:47: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1, changed state to up
00:00:47: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2, changed state to up
Router#
```

It's worth noting that this buffer can fill up quickly if you have a lot of traffic going through your router, such as ACL log entries.

Speaking from personal experience, we generally have explicit ACL `deny any` entries at the end of all of our ACLs for better code readability. One of those `deny any` policies was also set to log on a distribution switch. [Once we had an failure that required those log files](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5095/cisco-6509-supervisor-card-slot-boot-failure), we had found our buffer was filling up and clearing out the oldest entires. We had external logging facilities ([rsyslog](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/rsyslogd.8.html) on linux), but if your organization doesn't incorporate that and relies on the internal buffer, you'll need to remember that it might not be there when you need it.